# Can any FOSS ssh server enforce validity checks during the lifetime of a connect?

Tags: ssh

OpenSSH (and I guess probably others) check that a user exists and has valid access credentials at the time a connection is formed.

Can OpenSSH (or any other production-quality FOSS ssh server) be configured to re-check the validity of a connection from time to time?  For example, check that the user still exists and is still allowed to connect via ssh?  Or maybe check that the key used to connect is still valid for this user?

Comment: Tip: kill all processes of the user when you disable him.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, authentication is a gatekeeper, your credentials are only validated upon entry and your resulting environment is cached and remains valid as long as your session remains valid.
Neither do PAM modules require re-validation during a session.

You'll need to actively terminate processes owned by a specific user with for instance `pkill -9 -U UID` after you revoke their account.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this out of the box. The most basic solution is what HBruijn suggested.

However, if you have something like centralized authentication, that, of course, might not work, as the user would not be local and the killing would need to go distributed.

I would use pam_exec on the PAM session and have a task running in background that does the check and the killing.

`session     optional    pam_exec.so quiet /usr/local/bin/my-permisions-checking-binary`.